# Getting template view visible to outside parameters

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, templates

In XAML world i have an issue with exposing data of the template/style to view, which is using this template/style. Here's an example. 
First Style template:

```
<Style TargetType="myStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="myStyle">
                    <telerik:RadGridView Name="SomeName"
                             ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding SomeSource}"

                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeBinding}" Header="SomeHeader"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeBinding2}" Header="SomeHeader2" />
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeBinding3}" Header="SomeHeader3" IsReadOnly="True">
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Controls DataContext="{Binding SomeBinding4}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>                           
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And xaml file which will use it:

```
            <myStyle
            Grid.Row="0"
            SomeSource="{Binding SomeExternalSource}">

            <!-- I want here behaviour that will interact with myStyle Columns for example exporting this data to excel-->

            </myStyle>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Okay, i will remember that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create custom `Controls` or `Views` and you want them to have some (technical) interface so that you can use xaml markup or code to interact with your custom type, I recommend you add public `DependencyProperties`.

Imagine you have a control *MySpecialGrid*

```
public class MySpecialGrid : Control
{
    ctor() {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MySpecialGrid);
        Columns = new RadGridViewColumnsConfiguration();
    }

    public RadGridViewColumnsConfiguration Columns
    {
        get { return (RadGridViewColumnsConfiguration) GetValue( ColumnsProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ColumnsProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Columns", typeof( RadGridViewColumnsConfiguration),
        typeof( MySpecialGrid), null );
}
```

the default style for *MySpecialGrid*

```
<Style TargetType="MySpecialGrid">
  <Setter Property="Columns">
    <Setter.Value>
      <RadGridViewColumnsConfiguration>
        <GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeBinding}" Header="SomeHeader"/>
        <GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeBinding2}" Header="SomeHeader2"/>
        <GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeBinding3}" Header="SomeHeader3">
          <GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <... />
            </DataTemplate>
          </GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewDataColumn>
      </RadGridViewColumnsConfiguration>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="MySpecialGrid">
        <RadGridView Columns="{TemplateBinding Columns}"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

you can now access it from outside the control like this:

```
<MySpecialGrid x:Name="FeeblefezerDataGrid" ... />
<MyExcelExportButton Content="Export To Excel"
    ColumnsConfiguration="{Binding ElementName=FeeblefezerDataGrid, Path=Columns}"/>
```